# Why I need to remove and add dll reference every time in Visual Studio .NET

Tags: c#

I am adding one dll reference to my project. Whenever I modify the dll, I copy the dll the same folder overwriting the old one. But my compiler starts giving errors on the dll methods. Every time I have to remove the dll reference from the project and re-add the reference to build it.

My question is, why I need to remove and add reference every time? .NET should take the new dll automatically?

Comment: Versioning issue. But you should be referencing the project, NOT the dll directly

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, this appears to be a versioning issue. An alternative to adding the project to your solution (if you don't want it in there for some reason, or you have a requirement to reference the dll directly) is to modify your reference so that it doesn't look for a specific version.

1. Find the reference to the built assembly in the 'References' project folder
2. Right click on the reference
3. Change 'Specific Version' to false

hth

Comment: This was really helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have one project depending on the other, put them in the same solution and add the dependant project as a "Project Reference" rather than referencing the DLL directly.

Alternatively, if you want to use an assembly in multiple places, you can create a NuGet package. You can place these in either public or private feeds - and then add the dependency using NuGet.

If you do either of these the dependency will be managed for you.

Comment: This is not an answer to the actual question.